# kotlinx-serialization class marked @Serializable does not have the .serializer() extension function

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I have the following data class

```
@Serializable
data class Income(val id: String, 
                  val description: String, 
                  val amount: Int, 
                  val Time: Date, 
                  val userId: String)
```

now when I try to use the .serializer() function it says that the .serializer() is not defined for Income class so my project doesn't compile.

```
    val response = Json.stringify(Income.serializer(), Incomes)
    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK,response)
```

I Looked twice on the documentation in the [readme.md](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#quick-example). 
Even watched the announcement video from [KotlinConf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhKTIFlNrC4)

Did anyone have the same problem. What am i doing wrong??

Edit:

I tried to just copy paste the samples from the readme.md and had the same problem.

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*

@Serializable
data class Data(val a: Int, val b: String = "42")

fun main() {
    // Json also has .Default configuration which provides more reasonable settings,
    // but is subject to change in future versions
    val json = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable)
    // serializing objects
    val jsonData = json.stringify(Data.serializer(), Data(42))
    // serializing lists
    val jsonList = json.stringify(Data.serializer().list, listOf(Data(42)))
    println(jsonData) // {"a": 42, "b": "42"}
    println(jsonList) // [{"a": 42, "b": "42"}]

    // parsing data back
    val obj = json.parse(Data.serializer(), """{"a":42}""") // b is optional since it has default value
    println(obj) // Data(a=42, b="42")
}
```

This does not compile as well in my code.
I'm currently using Kotlin 1.3..61 and 
kotlinx-serialization-runtime 0.14.0

Comment: Did you include the compiler plugin?

Comment: That was it! I feel so stupid for missing it! Can you please post that as an answer so i will mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In addition to the `kotlinx-serialization-runtime` dependency you also need to [add the plugin](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#using-the-plugins-block)

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") // or kotlin("jvm") or any other kotlin plugin
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.10"
}
```

with the same version as Kotlin itself.

Comment: In order to get rid of the error on ktor I needed to add  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.4.10' to the plugins section of my build.gradle file

Comment: Bit late to the party here, but any chance you can explain to me why we need both the plugin and the dependency to be able to run this code? My limited understanding of Gradle is that plugins provide tasks to be used during the build process itself, whereas dependencies represent the classpath to be used during compilation and/or runtime. Not including this plugin doesn't prevent the code from being compiled, but it's necessary for it to run. Why?

Comment: The question says it does prevent the code from being compiled: "it says that the .serializer() is not defined for Income class so my project doesn't compile". If in your case it doesn't, this is surprising to me as well.

Comment: Hmm. Even assuming that the code doesn't compile without including the plugin, why would the compilation of any code be dependent on the plugins in a Gradle build file?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Plugins can: 1) generate code which is needed by the code the user writes; 2) change compilation options; 3) in Kotlin's case, activate compiler plugins. All of these can affect compilation.

Comment: Thank you - I had the same problem with a quarkus project, and the addition of the serialization plugin fixed it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem that my Navigation Drawer XML file didn't recognize my serializable class, for that I had to extend the `java.io.Serializable` myself, bit for kotlin it was fine:

```
@Serializable
data class Income(val id: String, 
                  val description: String, 
                  val amount: Int, 
                  val Time: Date, 
                  val userId: String) : java.io.Serializable
```

Comment: This is great, I tried everything else and nothing was working