# How do I apply a plugin in a .kts (Kotlin script) file?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-script

Kotlin script (`.main.kts`) files have the idea of providing executable Kotlin code in **ONE single standalone file**, which is immensely convenient for scripting or when sharing code snippets on StackOverflow for example. In contrast to that, currently almost all Java/Kotlin uses a build system (e.g. gradle) with cryptic build files and a deep folder structure.

While I like the Kotlin script idea a lot, it seems to be barely used, with only 22 questions on StackOverflow and *extremely sparse* documentation and precious few Google results. I am able to pull in dependencies using `@file:DependsOn` inside of the actual script rather than the traditional build file:

**`build.gradle`**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.0'
}
```

**`foo.main.kts`**:

```
@file:DependsOn("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.0")
```

However, I can't find a way to use "apply plugin" in my `.main.kts` file. It's not used in any of the code snippets I found online.

**`build.gradle`**:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'
```

**`foo.main.kts`**:

```
???
```

For reference, I attached an MWE below. The error message says the class `Node` is not serializable, but as pointed out [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60467661/2111778) **that message is misleading and the actual issue that `apply plugin` is missing**, which I do not know how to use outside of a `build.gradle` file:

```kotlin
@file:DependsOn("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.0")

import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

@Serializable
data class Node (val numbers: List<Int>)

val h = Json.decodeFromString<Node>(""" {"numbers": [1, 2, 3]} """)
```

Run it on Ubuntu:

```sh
snap install kotlin
kotlin foo.main.kts
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, my goal is to find the `.main.kts` "analogue" of the `build.gradle` file. The script obviously does not have its own build file.

Comment: apply(plugin="kotlinx-serialization")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`kotlinx-serialization` is a Gradle plugin, which adds to pipeline same-named compiler plugin - it generates the `serializer()` method for classes annotated with `@Serializable`.

When you compile Kotlin code with `kotlinc` compiler, you can attach the plugin by providing the path to its JAR file (it's bundled with the compiler) using the `-Xplugin=/snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlinx-serialization-compiler-plugin.jar` compiler option.

For `.kts` files, there is a `@file:CompilerOptions` annotation, but currently (in Kotlin 1.5.10) this particular key is not supported (`warning: the following compiler arguments are ignored on script compilation: -Xplugin`)

**Command line**

On the command line you may use

```sh
kotlinc -script -Xplugin="/snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlinx-serialization-compiler-plugin.jar" foo.main.kts
```

**Script header**

As a workaround you may use this shebang:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env -S kotlinc -script -Xplugin="/snap/kotlin/current/lib/kotlinx-serialization-compiler-plugin.jar"
```

To run your script you need to turn it into an executable:

```sh
chmod u+x foo.main.kts
```

Now it could be run with:

```
./foo.main.kts
```

Comment: Vote for this feature: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47384

Comment: Great answer! I have version 2.28 of env/coreutils but the `-S` option is only on 2.30 or better. But just calling the script with `kotlinc` and the `-Xplugin` option works!

Comment: Take a look at [kscript](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript) project - it allows to pass compiler options with `//COMPILER_OPTS` (highly likely `-Xplugin` is supported) and  provides more feature-rich support for kotlin scripting